# Pyspark - sequential estimate function. - parallel

Tags: pyspark, sequential

I have a func. like below and want calculate the estimated groupBy the
key. The data needs to be sorted within the group by time.

It looks like it isn't easy/possible to do with spark.df so I tried with rdd, but even when I
use a customized partitioning (number of groups) a "shuffle" in the part/recors? returns wrong results partially (not in all groups).

How can I avoid this and calculate it in parallel with a clean grouping given the sorting?
Thanks in advance, Christian

## func

```
def estimate(rows):
    estimated = float(0.0)
    result = []

    for row in rows:
        time, key, available, level, reduction, total = row
        if level >= 0.3:
           estimated += float(available -  reduction)
           estimated = min(estimated, total)
        else:
            estimated =float(0.0)
        result.append((time, key, available, level, reduction, total, estimated))
    return iter(result)
```

#### Approach with mapPartitions

```
def partition_func(key):
    return hash(key)

rdd = df_input.rdd.map(lambda row: (row["key"], row))
partitioned_rdd = rdd.partitionBy(numPartitions=n, partitionFunc=partition_func)


new_df = (partitioned_rdd.map(lambda x: x[1])        
          .mapPartitions(estimate)
          .toDF()
         )
```

Approach with groupByKeys.flatMapValues(estimate) also isn't clean in the parallelization.

Answer (score 1):

I would group the dataframe by `key` then use `applyInPandas` to calculate the estimated values for each group. This approach will distribute groups corresponding to each unique keys in parallel for efficient computation

```
def estimate(pdf):
    acc, result = 0, []
    pdf = pdf.sort_values('time')

    for r in pdf.itertuples():
        acc += r.available - r.reduction
        acc = min(acc, r.total)
        result.append(acc)

    return pdf.assign(estimated=result)

schema = T.StructType([*df_input.schema.fields, T.StructField('estimated', T.DoubleType())])
df_result = df_input.groupBy('key').applyInPandas(estimate, schema=schema)
```

Comment: Perfect thank you, I checked it but wasn't sure how to return. The applyInPandas is faster then expected.